# How does XSLT do lookup values with comma separated String?

Tags: xml, string, xslt, lookup

I figured how to do a String lookup and how to parse comma separated String respectively. However I wonder if there is an efficient way to meet both of these two requirements. Here is my source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
     <MATRIX>
     <DATA_RECORD>
      <COMPONENT1>1, 2</COMPONENT1> 
      <COMPONENT2>6, 7, 8, 9</COMPONENT2>  
     </DATA_RECORD>
    </MATRIX>
```

I expect to generate the following XML by parsing the comma separated String and using each of the token to do a lookup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <MATRIX>
     <DATA_RECORD>
      <COMPONENT1>A, B</COMPONENT1> 
      <COMPONENT2>F, G, H, I</COMPONENT2>  
     </DATA_RECORD>
    </MATRIX>
```

Here is my lookup XML(COMPONENT_LOOKUPLIST.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <MAIN>
      <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>1</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>A</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
      <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>2</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>B</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
        <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>3</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>C</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
      <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>4</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>D</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
        <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>5</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>E</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
      <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>6</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>F</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
        <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>7</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>G</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
      <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>8</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>H</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
      <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>9</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>I</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
    </MAIN>
```

I am a beginner of XSLT. Can some XSLT experts share some idea or provide a sample code? I got the token code from Jeni's web site:

```
 <xsl:template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:param name="string" />
          <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','" />
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$delimiter and contains($string, $delimiter)">
              <token>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $delimiter)" />
              </token>

              <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" 
                                select="substring-after($string, $delimiter)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter" />
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
              <token><xsl:value-of select="$string" /></token>

            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">    
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="/MATRIX/DATA_RECORD/COMPONENT1"></xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">    
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="/MATRIX/DATA_RECORD/COMPONENT2"></xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
```

and wrote a lookup:

```
<xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('COMPONENT_LOOKUPLIST.xml')/MAIN/DATA_RECORD"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="//DATA_RECORD">

 <token>
  <xsl:for-each select="*">      
   <xsl:value-of select="$lookup[COMPONENT_ID = current()]/COMPONENT_NAME"/>        
          </xsl:for-each>   
          </token>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

But it seems challenging to combine these two together.

Thank you.

Comment: You want us to do the work for you?

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using, and what processor?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime? In that case you can easily do e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="by-id" match="DATA_RECORD" use="COMPONENT_ID"/>

<xsl:param name="lk-doc-url" select="'COMPONENT_LOOKUPLIST.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="lk-doc" select="document($lk-doc-url)"/>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'COMPONENT')]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="for $id in tokenize(., ', ') return key('by-id', $id, $lk-doc)/COMPONENT_NAME"
       separator=", "/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

[edit]
Here is a complete and tested sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">



<xsl:key name="by-id" match="DATA_RECORD" use="COMPONENT_ID"/>

<xsl:param name="lk-doc-url" select="'test2013013103.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="lk-doc" select="document($lk-doc-url)"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'COMPONENT')]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="for $id in tokenize(., ', ') return key('by-id', $id, $lk-doc)/COMPONENT_NAME"
       separator=", "/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply that with Saxon 9.4 to the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
     <MATRIX>
     <DATA_RECORD>
      <COMPONENT1>1, 2</COMPONENT1> 
      <COMPONENT2>6, 7, 8, 9</COMPONENT2>  
     </DATA_RECORD>
    </MATRIX>
```

with the lookup file `test2013013103.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <MAIN>
      <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>1</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>A</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
      <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>2</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>B</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
        <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>3</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>C</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
      <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>4</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>D</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
        <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>5</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>E</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
      <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>6</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>F</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
        <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>7</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>G</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
      <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>8</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>H</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
      <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_ID>9</COMPONENT_ID>
        <COMPONENT_NAME>I</COMPONENT_NAME>    
      </DATA_RECORD>
    </MAIN>
```

the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MATRIX>
     <DATA_RECORD>
      <COMPONENT1>A, B</COMPONENT1>
      <COMPONENT2>F, G, H, I</COMPONENT2>
     </DATA_RECORD>
    </MATRIX>
```

So my suggestion works, I am not sure what is different in your case that you don't get any content.

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for looking into this. I am open to 2.0. But I just parse the XML and only empty XML <COMPONENT1></COMPONENT1>
<COMPONENT2></COMPONENT2>. Anything missing here?

Comment: I didn't post a complete stylesheet, just tried to give you an idea. But I have now written a complete and working stylesheet where the above sample is used as posted, with the exception of the URL of the lookup file. I will edit the answer and provide details.

Comment: It looks like it was something to do with my XMLSpy processor. You solution does work perfectly with Saxon. Thank you so much to come up in such a sleek way. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with XSLT1.0, one solution could be to amend the **tokenize** template to do the look-up, rather than spitting up **token** elements (If you kept with the **token** elements, you would have to do a two-pass transform to transform these back to strings based on your look-up).

So, instead of doing this in the **tokenize** template

```
<token>
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $delimiter)" />
</token>
```

Do, this instead

```
<xsl:value-of select="$lookup[COMPONENT_ID=normalize-space(substring-before($string, $delimiter))]/COMPONENT_NAME"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html"/>

   <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('C:\COMPONENT_LOOKUPLIST.xml')/MAIN/DATA_RECORD"/>

   <xsl:template match="DATA_RECORD/*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="tokenize">
      <xsl:param name="string"/>
      <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$delimiter and contains($string, $delimiter)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$lookup[COMPONENT_ID=normalize-space(substring-before($string, $delimiter))]/COMPONENT_NAME"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
               <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $delimiter)"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$lookup[COMPONENT_ID=normalize-space($string)]/COMPONENT_NAME"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<MATRIX>
   <DATA_RECORD>
      <COMPONENT1>A,B</COMPONENT1>
      <COMPONENT2>F,G,H,I</COMPONENT2>
   </DATA_RECORD>
</MATRIX>
```

Note, this does remove the spaces too, but hopefully that isn't an issue...

EDIT: If you do want to keep the spaces, you do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="current" select="substring-before($string, $delimiter)" />
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($current, normalize-space($current))" /> 
<xsl:value-of select="$lookup[COMPONENT_ID=normalize-space($)]/COMPONENT_NAME"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($current, normalize-space($current))" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. This is quick and works great. I do care the space though since later on I need parse it into a HTML.  With a space, the text can be wrap up properly. Will take a look whether I can add the space back. I am using XSLT 1.0 with Altova XMLSpy as a processor. I am wondering whether 2.0 having a better solution.

Comment: I've amended my answer to show how you can add spaces, but if you can use XSLT2.0, then Martin's solution is definitely the way to go.